# Set a column's default value to the concatenation of two other columns' values?

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgresql 8.1 database. In one table, there are three columns: `first_name`, `last_name`, `display_name`.

Is it possible to set the default value of `display_name` to be `first_name + " " + last_name`?

Comment: I know this is a more than 7 years old post. But, just to be curious, shouldn't you use view for this case? No update will be needed, no store overhead, no trigger needed etc?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use a trigger.

Here's some code you can use as a base. If you also need to handle UPDATEs, only a small change is required.

```
 create table people
 (
   first_name varchar(20),
   last_name varchar(20),
   display_name varchar(40)
 );
CREATE TABLE
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION people_insert() RETURNS trigger AS '
     BEGIN
         NEW.display_name := NEW.first_name||'' ''||NEW.last_name;
         RETURN NEW;
     END;
 ' LANGUAGE plpgsql;

 postgres=# CREATE FUNCTION


 CREATE TRIGGER people_insert BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON people FOR 
 EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE people_insert();

postgres=# CREATE TRIGGER
 insert into people values ('Larry','Ellison');

postgres=# INSERT 0 1

 postgres=# select * from people;
 first_name | last_name | display_name
------------+-----------+---------------
 Larry      | Ellison   | Larry Ellison
(1 row)

postgres=#
```

Comment: Thanks! Wouldn't the line `CREATE TRIGGER people_insert BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE...` handle the updating as well?

Comment: Oh, yeah. Must've been half asleep :)

Comment: display_name should probably be 41, if you care. Since you add a space between two 20 char columns.

Comment: I see that this solution adds about 15% overhead for insert operation :-(

Comment: Inserting Larry Ellison into Postgres 

Answer (score 18):

You don't need to actually *store* the value; you can create a function that can be referenced much like a generated column.  The one caveat is that references must always be qualified with the table or alias name.

```
CREATE TABLE person
  (
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    first_name text,
    last_name text NOT NULL
  );

INSERT INTO person
  VALUES
    (1, 'John', 'Smith'),
    (2, 'Jane', 'Doe'),
    (3, NULL, 'Prince');

CREATE FUNCTION display_name(rec person)
  RETURNS text
  STABLE
  LANGUAGE SQL
  COST 5
AS $$
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN $1.first_name IS NULL THEN ''
      ELSE $1.first_name || ' '
    END || $1.last_name;
$$;

SELECT p.id, p.display_name FROM person p;
```

The results:

```
 id | display_name 
----+--------------
  1 | John Smith
  2 | Jane Doe
  3 | Prince
(3 rows)
```

You can even index on the generated value, including using KNN searches based on trigram similarity.  For example:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm;

CREATE INDEX person_trgm_name
  ON person
  USING gist
  (display_name(person) gist_trgm_ops);

SELECT
    p.id,
    p.display_name,
    similarity(p.display_name, 'Jane')
  FROM person p
  ORDER BY p.display_name <-> 'Jane'
  LIMIT 2;
```

This type of search returns rows from the index scan in order of "distance" from the search string.  If you want to see how "close" they were, you could either use the distance operator (`<->`) or the `similarity()` function (which is 1 - distance).  A KNN search can return the K "nearest neighbors" very quickly, even with a very large data set.

Comment: I actually do need to store the value for backwards compatibility, but this is a pretty cool approach! The OCD part of me also wants there to be a check for NULL last names, but that would probably mean you have bigger data integrity issues to worry about at that point

Comment: Well, I declared `last_name` to be `NOT NULL` in my example. :-) We had name columns like that which were in the table and maintained by triggers and switched to this approach without much pain, but our framework always uses an alias and always qualifies references, so that part was easy. If you have code which isn't consistent about qualifying column references I can see where it could be a pain to track down all those cases.

Answer (score 3):

With the DEFAULT setting on a column table, nope.

Your best bet here is a TRIGGER with the NEW value for each column you want computed.

Answer (score 2):

Use **Generated Columns** (since Postgres 12).

```sql
CREATE TABLE users (
                       first_name   text NOT NULL,
                       last_name    text NOT NULL,
                       full_name    text, -- we can overwrite the display name here
                       display_name text GENERATED ALWAYS AS (coalesce(full_name, first_name || ' ' || last_name)) STORED
);
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/27j2r8eesSxqabcVs98ine/2)